# Base 16 encoding of Uint8Array.buffer data

Tags: javascript, encoding, binary

I am using javascript Uint8Array object.
I get a binary data out of it using '.buffer' property.

Due to some reasons I want to encode the binary data to base16 but I haven't got the clue yet.
Any help in the regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need

```
var b16 = "";
var u8 = [8,9,10,11]; // sample input

for(var x = 0; x < u8.length; x++) {
    b16 += pad2(u8[x].toString(16));
}

function pad2(str) {
    return (str.length < 2) ? "0"+str : str;
}

console.log(b16); // will return string "08090a0b"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = new Uint8Array(4);

function pad(str ) {
    return str.length < 2 ? "0" + str : str;
}

[].map.call( a, function(v) {
    return pad(v.toString(16));
}).join(""); //00000000
```